# Uisearchresultsupdating protocols is not recieving any datum

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

When I start to type on the search bar I am not receiving any datum via my protocols. My aim is to get data when is start type on the search bar in search controller.

Code:

```
class FirstViewController:UIViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating{
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.labels.text="sd"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let searchcontrol=UISearchController(searchResultsController:self)

        searchcontrol.searchResultsUpdater=self
        let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 65.0, width: 350.0, height: 45.0))

        subView.addSubview((searchcontrol.searchBar))
        searchcontrol.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchcontrol.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        view.addSubview(subView)
    }
}
```

Comment: One obvious issue is that `searchcontrol` goes out of scope at the end of `viewDidLoad` so the `UISearchController` gets deallocated because there is no strong reference to it.

Comment: how do we fix it ?@rmaddy

Comment: Make `searchcontrol` a property instead of a local variable.

Comment: if i do that way that leads to me  time error

Answer (score 0):

As rmaddy said, try something like this:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchcontrol.searchResultsUpdater=self
        let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 65.0, width: 350.0, height: 45.0))

        subView.addSubview((searchcontrol.searchBar))
        searchcontrol.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchcontrol.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        view.addSubview(subView)
    }

}

extension FirstViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating{

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.labels.text="sd"
    }

}
```